# Pyspark SIZE function works in itself, but in UDF it doesnt

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

[image]

Cannot understand why does SIZE work in itself, but not in an UDF. The output is IntegerType as it can be seen in the top picture.
[image]

Works with max for example.
[image]

Comment: `max()` is a python function as well and `size()` is not. With the `max()`, it might be referring to the python function call.

Comment: @samkart , but still, why shouldnt it work

Comment: [refer](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.UDFRegistration) - your function should be a python function, not a native spark one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@samkart your function should be a python function, not a native spark one.
Ah ok, this explains it.

Just curious, where is this mentioned in spark documentation?